# Creating Windows Print Driver

Tags: windows, printing, driver, wdk

I'm looking to create a print driver that will monitor jobs sent to a particular printer and add in a small amount of text to each page.  I have downloaded the WDK and have the bitmap example working, but the monitor examples are complicated.  The WDK documentation seems to be lacking any explanation of the samples.  I also don't see any Visual Studio templates for Windows Drivers (not sure if they are supposed to be installed as part of the WDK or not).

I think what I'm struggling the most with is seeing the overall approach.  Since this is printing to a printer (not file), I'm assuming I still need to use the printer's driver somehow.  So does that make what I'm trying to do a "Filter Driver"?  As you can tell, this is not something I've done before, so any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need to add in?  You can use the Mini Driver in the WinDDK and just hijack one of the commands.

If you need to add in something more you'll probably want a port monitor like [Redmon](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/) (or we are about to release one) that can take your job and route it to some application that modifies the data and then routes to the final printer.

If you just need to insert some items at the very start (inject some PCL or something) then you can use the [Windows separator page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102712) and insert the data at the start of the stream.

If you give some more detail about what exactly you need to modify or insert I can probably help a little more.

Comment: Thanks Douglas.  I need to monitor the port and when a print job is sent, I need to open a dialog to enter a client number and then add that number to the bottom of every page in the print job.  I don't think I can just add a printer property in the print dialog because it is a required field that should not have a default.

Comment: I should also mention that I am developing this for Windows Server 2003, so it doesn't appear that Redmon is an option.  Also, I don't think the Windows separator page will work either.

Comment: You will run into a problem doing it at the port level with a RedMon as you are on a server, unless you want to install the Monitor on every workstation.  You'll need to do some extra work inside a driver.  This can be done but I've never put a dialog box inside a driver.  Many manufactures do so it's possible. I'll do some investigation on my end of the next day or two.